normal derivate boundary
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash \overline{D}$, where $D$ is a bounded domain and consider $d$ a smooth version of the distance to the boundary of $\partial D\in C^{\infty}$. Determine the normal derivative $\partial\nu (f/d^{\alpha-1})|_{\partial\Omega}$ with $\alpha>0$.
My approach: Note that,
$$\partial_{\nu}(\frac{f}{d^{\alpha-1}})|_{\partial\Omega}=$$
$$\partial_{\nu}((fd^{-\alpha})d)|_{\partial\Omega}=[d\nabla(fd^{-\alpha})+fd^{-\alpha}\nabla d]|_{\partial\Omega}=-fd^{-\alpha}|_{\partial\Omega}\nu$$
where $\nu$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial\Omega$.
But in case $\alpha=1$, I feel that this definition is not correct with what I would expect in the usual case.
Any way, also I can see the following,
$$\partial_{\nu}(\frac{f}{d^{\alpha-1}})|_{\partial\Omega}=[d^{1-\alpha}\nabla f + f(1-\alpha)d^{-\alpha}\nabla d]\cdot\nu|_{\partial\Omega}$$
Therefore, I feel that the notion of normal derivative on the boundary of $\partial\Omega$ is not well defined, can someone help me deal with these terms, greetings
